# What is the result of adding a number to a char *?

Tags: c++, pointers

I'm converting an algorithm from C++, which I haven't touched in 10+ years, and I'm just wondering if someone can tell me what `(char *)+2` results in?

The exact code:

```
uint32_t SuperFastHash (const char * data, int len) {
    ...
    tmp = (get16bits (data+2) << 11) ^ hash;
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It gives a pointer that's two characters further along the string/array than `data`.

For example, if `data` pointed to `"hello world"`, then `(data + 2)` would point to the first letter `l`.

Comment: So... if data is an array of characters, `hello world`, it points at the first `l`?

Comment: @cwolves: This is incredible. I've just added an example that's *identical* to your comment! What are the chances of that? :)

Comment: @Joachim Isaksson: Then `const char* const data = "Hello World"; const char* c(data+2);` wouldn't compile, right? But it does.

Comment: @Auwald I was referring to that the answer said that data+2 advanced the pointer. It's been changed now, so I'll remove the comment as to not cause confusion.

Answer (score 1):

It is the same as &data[2].

The address of the third member of the array.